# long long int ans = a*b VS long long int ans = (long long int) a*b

Tags: c++

I've written a code:

```
int a = 1000000000, b = 1000000000;
long long int ans = a * b;
cout << ans << '\n';
```

this code is causing overflow. I understand that a * b is causing the problem but I have taken long long int variable to keep a*b.
But look at the following code:

```
int a = 1000000000, b = 1000000000;
long long int ans = (long long int)a * b;
cout << ans << '\n';
```

it's working fine causing no overflow. Does it make any temporary variable to hold the value when calculating? Please explain the reason behind this strange overflowing.

Comment: The reason of overflowing in the first snippet is that `a * b` is calculated as an `int` (the type of the operands), it doesn't matter that the type of the variable where that result is stored *after* the calculation is wider.

Comment: "a * b is calculated as an int"-- but where the digits are stored when the calculation process is going? Is it stored in a different temporary int variable or one of these variables a, b? @Bob__

Comment: This happens in [CPU registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register), the actual steps depend on the hardware / [microcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode). See e.g. [here](https://godbolt.org/z/KM8b147YG), where the values are extended (in registers) after or before `imul`.

Comment: I'd check out what are [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion), in particular integer promotion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes **two** temporary variables, `(long long int)a` and `(long long int)b`.  The second conversion is implicit.

Actual compilers might not bother, if the hardware has a 32*32->64 multiply, but officially the conversions have to occur. On 64 bits hardware, it's essentially free when you load an `int` in a 64 bit register.

Comment: Actually where does it keep the calculated product (a*b) before assigning the product to declared variable?

Comment: @JahirulSarker: In practice, in a CPU register. And in an optimized build, that register will be the same register used for `ans`, so the assignment does not take instructions.